# How do you disable inputs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to preface this question with an apology, I've only just started my coding/ unity journey 2 weeks ago and thought I'd start with a simple project. I want to make a 2D sliding block puzzle game similar to the one you can find in Zelda Twilight Princess.
I have a few different movement scripts that I've written and the two functions that I just can't get to work for me are disabling player input while the blocks are moving and making a block immobile once they're at rest so other blocks can stack against them instead of pushing them along with them.
I apologise if the question seems mind-numbingly stupid but I've been looking for over a week, trying to use a simple canMove bool, trying to use yield WaitForSeconds to measure if the blocks are in the same place. I just can't get anything to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movementver2: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public bool canMove = false;

    public const string UP = "up";
    public const string DOWN = "down";
    public const string LEFT = "left";
    public const string RIGHT = "right";

    string moveDirection;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        /*by using GetKeyDown, in this instance it only moves once and 
        not very far, requiring many key presses to move forward.*/
      if(canMove == true)
      {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
             moveDirection = UP;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            moveDirection = DOWN;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            moveDirection = RIGHT;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            moveDirection = LEFT;
        } 
      }
        
         
// if these are no else if statements, then this statement screws up the movement.
// If you remove it then all the movement acts accordingly.
       /* else
        {
            moveDirection = null;
        }     */ 
    }
    

// I am able to get this code to work identically with only if statement
// You can removes the else's and it still works - not sure why?
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        if(moveDirection == UP)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, moveSpeed);
        }

        if(moveDirection == DOWN)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -moveSpeed);
        }

         if(moveDirection == RIGHT)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
        }

         if(moveDirection == LEFT)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0);
        }


        /* if you remove this then the block will keep moving indefinately
        with  a single key press instead of moving once even if it's colliding. */
       /* else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }*/

       

    }
}
```

I know the code is clunky, it's the only one that I wrote that would allow the blocks to slide continuously until they collided with a wall.
Any help would prevent any further hair loss.

Comment: In this script you do not change the value of canMove so it will never reach the inputs and you are not applying any movement if you have other scripts that manage these plz send them.

Comment: Hi, I do have multiple movement scripts and the only one that was able to stop player input had a series of other baffling problems, such as bouncing which couldn't be turned off regardless of messing with mass or drag or physics materials, and rely on detecting colliding with a wall.
With this code I've tried over a dozen versions where I'm trying to stop Input.GetAnyKey, I've tried using a yield function to measure whether the block is moving to turn off controls, I've been all over this forum and unity forums and youtube videos, but I can't seem to shoehorn any solutions onto my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand the concept of the game, however: You don't change the value of canMove - it is public, so it may be in another script, but make sure you change it when you need to.
And you can disable the movement of an object by setting it's Rigidbody's `isKinematic` and possibly also `detectCollisions` to false

Comment: Hey thank you for commenting. Basically imagine a top down game, the aim is to push blocks of ice until they land but more importantly stay on a switch, this allows you to progress to the next level. I've tried a few times entering something that can switch canMove off but every time I received error codes that I just could not understand so I had to keep removing those lines of code. Also I need a method to be able to switch the rigidbody from dynamic to kinematic when stationary.
Thank you again for trying to help.